# .bat Batch file Command for windows 7

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat script. & In that script "set Targetfolder" & "set sourcefolder" commands are there. 
I want to remove the both commands & want to give these command after execution of the script. means It should be ask the targetfolder and sourceflder paths.

Because, I have n numbers of Task & different Targefolder & sourcefolder path, however script doing the same function & for those all tasks I would have to create scripts..so, I am thinking rather then to do this I can keep the contain same in the batch file and only can put the Targetfolder & sourcefolder path.

In short that script should ask Targetfolder & sourcefolder, after giving those path It should be complete the script.

So, could any one suggest that how can I do this? PLEASE

The script has the below containt :

```
@echo off
setlocal
set DateFolder=04.2013
set TargetFolder=F:\Financial\Data\%DateFolder%\Final Reports

:: copy the newest file from AccruntPnLMTD and rename it to PNL.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccruntPnLMTD" "%TargetFolder%\PNL.csv"

:: copy the newest file from AccountPnlMTD and rename it to AC.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccountPnlMTD" "%TargetFolder%\AC.csv"

:: copy the newest file from ExpensesMTD and rename it to EXPMTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesMTD" "%TargetFolder%\EXPMTD.csv"

:: copy the newest file from ExpensesYTD and rename it to EXPYTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD" "%TargetFolder%\EXPYTD.csv"

:: copy the newest file from AccrualPnLYTD and rename it to PNLYTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccrualPnLYTD" "%TargetFolder%\PNLYTD.csv"

:: copy the newest file from AccountYTD and rename it to ACYTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccountYTD" "%TargetFolder%\ACYTD.csv"

:: copy the newest file from BalanceMTD and rename it to BSMTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\BalanceMTD" "%TargetFolder%\BSMTD.csv"

:: copy the newest file from BalanceYTD and rename it to BSYTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\BalanceYTD" "%TargetFolder%\BSYTD.csv"

:: copy the newest file from FinancialStmtMTD and rename it to FSMTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\FinancialStmtMTD" "%TargetFolder%\FSMTD.csv"

:: copy the newest file from FinancialStmtYTD and rename it to FSYTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\FinancialStmtYTD" "%TargetFolder%\FSYTD.csv"


:: Done
goto :eof

:copyAndRename
set SourceFolder=%~1
set TargetFile=%~2

:: Find the newest file in the source folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /od /a-d "%SourceFolder%"') do set "NewestFile=%%F"

:: copy and rename it to the target
copy "%SourceFolder%\%NewestFile%" "%TargetFile%"


:: Done with this subroutine
goto :eof
```

Comment: You should clarify your question, it is nearly unreadable.

Comment: Hi Endoro, I have update the contains of the scripts..

Comment: Ok. Is the source folder for the latest file that is renamed to PNL.csv always going to be F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccruntPnLMTD? The same goes for the other files listed.

Comment: Yes..All source folders will remain same every month..there will not changes in source path & the same process follow for the others. In those folders latest CSV files will be auto saved by an application & I need that latest file to the target path (which is common for all CSV files).

Comment: Hi Matt...I am awaiting your response.pl treate this as humble request...thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to use %1 and %2 in your batch file, like

```
set Targetfolder = %1
set sourcefolder = %2
```

Then call the file like this:

```
file.bat path1 path2
```

You can then just create a shortcut with the right values in (or several shortcuts for your different needs).

Of course there's no checking in the above, might want to add that.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal
set TargetFolder= %1, set sourcefolder= %2...put the commands, but whare I need to update "file.bat path1 path2?

Comment: %1 and %2 are arguments that you feed to the batch file when you run it. In order to do so, you have to run the `.bat` file from a `CMD` prompt or, as Daniel mentioned, create a shortcut to the batch file then edit it to add the sourcefolder and targetfolder. Do you want to be able to double click to run the batch file and then specify the source and target folders?

Comment: Hi Daniel Morritt..I update the batch file using set Targetfolder =%1 & set sourcefolder =%2. now, I should rename file name "file.bat path1 path2" & How can I create a shortcut with the right valuse?..sorry to bother u again..can u discribe more..thx

Comment: No, don't rename the file, just save it without the paths %1 and %2 represent the arguments that you are passing to the file, then right click the original file.bat and select **Create shortcut**.  In the shortcut set the **Target** to `file.bat path1 path2`.

Comment: I have create shortcut..then need to go on properties of shortcut and should I updated "file.bat path1 path2" under the target field?

Comment: @nikiniki: That's right. But make sure you *don't enclose the entire command line* in double quotes. That is, it could be this: `D:\path\file.bat path1 path2` or this: `"D:\path\file.bat" "path1" "path2"` but *not* this: `"D:\path\file.bat path1 path2"`.

Comment: Path1 & Path2 means I shuld update the Targetfolder & sourcefolder path right?..if yes...it's not working I updated the target field like this : "D:\path\file.bat" "F:\Financial\Data\" "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\"

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `SET /P` and have to type in the source and target folders manually each time or you could use my BrowseFolder routine and pick it from a dialog. Give this a try.

```
@echo off
setlocal

Call :BrowseFolder "Choose Target folder" "F:\Financial\Data\"
Set TargetFolder=%Result% 

Call :BrowseFolder "Choose Source folder" "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\"
Set SourceFolder=%Result% 


:: copy the newest file from AccruntPnLMTD and rename it to PNL.csv
call :copyAndRename %SourceFolder% "%TargetFolder%\PNL.csv"

:: copy the newest file from AccrualPnLMTD and rename it to AC.csv
call :copyAndRename "%SourceFolder%" "%TargetFolder%\AC.csv"

:: Done
goto :eof

:copyAndRename
set SourceFolder=%~1
set TargetFile=%~2

:: Find the newest file in the source folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /od /a-d "%SourceFolder%"') do set "NewestFile=%%F"

:: copy and rename it to the target
copy "%SourceFolder%\%NewestFile%" "%TargetFile%"

:: Done with this subroutine
goto :eof


:BrowseFolder
set Result=
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
set cmd="%temp%\_.cmd"
for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
>%vbs% echo set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
>>%vbs% echo set shell=WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
>>%vbs% echo set f=shell.BrowseForFolder(0,%1,0,%2) 
>>%vbs% echo if typename(f)="Nothing" Then  
>>%vbs% echo wscript.echo "set Result=Dialog Cancelled" 
>>%vbs% echo WScript.Quit(1)
>>%vbs% echo end if 
>>%vbs% echo set fs=f.Items():set fi=fs.Item() 
>>%vbs% echo p=fi.Path:wscript.echo "set Result=" ^& p
cscript //nologo %vbs% > %cmd%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%cmd%) do %%a
for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
goto :eof
```

Comment: Hi Matt, ...I am doing the same way like you suggest but it's not working.. However, the dialog boxes are appearing and I give the right path. but it's giving the error below: File not found The system can not find the path specified.

Comment: Change the code to add the Echo's as above. Run the script from a `CMD` prompt and post your results. Copy and paste them directly from the `CMD` window.

Comment: Hi Matt..still not working, and no error massage this time. It's asking both the path only for one time n ..It should be also second thim as well.B'z there are two files to be copy and rename.

Comment: I've modified my BrowseFolder routine. Copy and paste it into a new batch file and run it. You should get 2 popup windows that let you pick a folder and the path. Both of those should be echo'd to the `CMD` window. Is this what happens?

Comment: yes I got 2 popup but there should be 4 popups b'z two files should be copy and rename from diffrent source and coman target..but after 2popup (Source and target) it got finished without any output and error msg.

Comment: You can call the BrowseFolder routine as many times as you want. The output from it will always be in the Environment variable **Result**. I'm not sure why it isn't echoing the paths to the `CMD` window. It works fine for me. Try it now. You should get popup windows saying set Result="path you picked". Is that the case?

Comment: I also gatting the same popuup saying set Result="Path" but still output not done. it's showing error msg "c:\Docume~1\niki\Locals~1\Temp|f\_.cmd.

Comment: Hi matt..please lookinto once, I am very near to resolve this..please.

Comment: Here I am explaining it agin for you the all process: By this script: I am copying & rename the latest csv file from variable source ( approx 10 source folders) to the Targetfolder (which is common).

like :  "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\FS"  from this path macro pickup latest file and will copy and rename to target folder.
 "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\FA"  from this path macro pickup latest file and will copy and rename to target folder...
As I mantion that I want's to do this by selecting the source and target folder after run the batch.

Comment: I understand your process. I don't think the issue you're experiencing is related to that though. It seems as if the created batch file isn't running in order to create the Result variable. I've modified the New Browseforfolder routine with some additional diagnostic code. Run it and **COPY and PASTE** the results from the `CMD` window here.

Comment: Hi Matt..thx for help! can you please arrange all containts of the batch in order. (concept of newestfils...sited in my question) so I can run it properly.seems I am not putting all containts in order..Thx

Comment: I'm missing something here. Are the files always renamed to the same thing? Like PNL.CSV and AC.csv? You say there are 10 source folders which would imply there are 8 more .csv files, correct? Are the files being overwritten everyday or whenever you run the script? If this is the case, list all of the filenames like this: PNL.csv, AC.csv, File3.csv, etc..

Comment: yes..like latest file from "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccruntPnLMTD" will always rename as "PNL.csv"...I'll do this activity only once in a month..every month I'll make a new folder at target path "F:\Financial\Data\%DateFolder%\Final Reports" in this path datefolder which is 04.2013 will change next month 05.2013.